# Creating a column with conditions over multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','a'])
```

I need to create a column considering the variation on the other column.

Following this result:

| Letter | Number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 0 |
| b | 0 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 0 |
| a | 1 |

Every time the letter change, I need to put a 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `shift`

I'm assuming that `df` is what OP provided

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','a'])
```

Then reasigned the first column to a series `letter`

```
letter = df.iloc[:, 0]

pd.DataFrame({
    'Letter': letter,
    'Number': letter.shift().ne(letter).astype(int)
})

  Letter  Number
0      a       1
1      a       0
2      a       0
3      a       0
4      b       1
5      b       0
6      b       0
7      c       1
8      c       0
9      a       1
```